Maximum value of $\sin(x)-\sin^3(x)$ without using calculus
Can you find the maximum value of $\sin(x)-\sin^3(x)$ without using calculus. I tried AM-GM but could not find anything useful

can you maximize $x-x^3$ in the relevant range?

Maybe use the fact that $\sin x - \sin^3 x = \frac{1}{4}(\sin x + \sin 3x),$ and then seek to maximize $\sin x + \sin 3x$ (perhaps by looking at where maximums of $\sin x$ and $\sin 3x$ coincide).

@DaveL.Renfro Interesting idea...where do they coincide, though? (If $\sin(x)=1$ then $\sin(3x)=3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)=-1$)

@Chris Lewis: I was thinking of periodicity of their graphs perhaps leading to a common maximum, but it seems their maximum locations will never coincide. The maximums of $\sin 3x$ occur at $(4k+1)$-multiples of $\pi/6.$ The maximums of $\sin x$ occur at $(4k + 1)$-multiples of $\pi/2,$ or at $3(4k+1)$-multiples of $\pi/6.$ However, $4k+1$ integers are $1$ more than multiples of $4$ and $3(4k+1) = 4(3k) + 3$ integers are $3$ more than multiples of $4.$ Since no integer that is $1$ more than a multiple of $4$ is also $3$ more than a multiple of $4 ; \ldots$

Equivalently, let us look at $f(x) = x-x^3$ for $x\in [-1, 1]$.  Clearly the maximum is for some $x\in (0, 1)$, as for other $x$ in the domain, $f(x)=x(1-x^2)\leqslant 0$.
To use AM-GM, consider equivalently maximising $2f^2$, an increasing function for positive $f$. We can write $2f^2(x) = (2x^2)(1-x^2)(1-x^2)$, as a product of three positive terms which have a constant sum, viz. $2$.  Hence this is maximised by AM-GM when the terms are equal, i.e. when $2x^2=1-x^2\implies x =\frac1{\sqrt3}$.
Hence $f(x)$ is maximum for the same value, i.e $f(\frac1{\sqrt3})=\frac2{3\sqrt3}$.

We apply Vieta's Formulas.
Let $a$ be the maximum value and render $u=\sin x$. We see $a$ such that
$-u^3+u-a$
will have a double root between $u=0$ and $1$. Call the double root $r_2$ and the remainung nondegenerate root $r_1$. Then
$-u^3+u-a=-(u-r_1)(u-r_2)^2=-u^2+(r_1+2r_2)u^2-(2r_1r_2+r_2^2)+r_1r_2^2.$
So matching like-power terms gives
$r_1+2r_2=0, r_1=-2r_2$
$2r_1r_2+r_2^2=-3r_2^2=-1$
$r_1r_2^2=-a$
The first two matching equations, with $u$ requied to be positive for a positive value of $u-u^3$ with $|u|\le1$, imply $r_2=1/\sqrt3$. So $r_1=-2r_2=-2/\sqrt3$ and the final matching equation gives
$a=2/(3\sqrt3)$
as the maximum value of the cubic polynomial within the trigonometric domain.

Drive-by downvotes suck. Agree or disagree?

This is equivalent to finding the local extrema of the cubic function $f(u)=u-u^{3}$ under the substitution $u=\sin x$. Observe that if a cubic function attains a local extremum $m$ then $-u^3+u-m$ has a double root at $u=m$. Hence, it can be factored into $a(u-p)(u-q)^2$ for constants $a,p,q$. Considering coefficients, deduce what these constants must be to find $m$. Then show that the value is attained by the original trigonometric expression.
